# Using javascript variavl in jQuery Flip plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have this code. In the 'content' section, I want a variable - currentCard - to be displayed.

Here is the code. Any help is much appreciated!

```
 $("#middle").flip({
    direction:'rl',
    content:'currentCard',
    color:'#fff'
})
```

Comment: Then don't put it in quotes?

Comment: I've tried it, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's weird that without quotes isn't working for you, try this code:

```
var currentCard = "card123";
console.log(currentCard);

$("#middle").flip({
    direction:'rl',
    content:currentCard,
    color:'#fff'
})
```

To see the console output, use the developer tools of your browser or Firebug.

If this code works with "cart123", delete the line that defines currentCard and leave the console print to make sure the value of this variable is what you think it is.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your code say:

```
$("#content").flip({  //changed to 'content' from 'middle'
direction:'rl',
content:currentCard, //remove the quotes, because with the quotes, it'll anyway never get the value of the variable.
color:'#fff'
});
```

Comment: Also, be sure your variable "currentCard" has a value and is accessible by this code on runtime.